# todcursoradapter context cannot be applied

Tags: android

I am always facing problem with context ,there is error here in this code becode of `this`

```
   TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
```

I tried to add `getapplicationcontext` still facing error

this is the class

```
public class Search extends Activity {
  //  ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String myJSON;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_desc ="description";

    JSONArray peoples = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

    ListView list;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
// Get access to the underlying writeable database
        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
// Query for items from the database and get a cursor back
        Cursor todoCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM OBJECTS", null);
        // Find ListView to populate
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
       TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
       // lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
    }
```

this is the consctructor of the class

```
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
            super(context, cursor, 0);
        }
```

Comment: as in `TodoCursorAdapter` class constructor which is taking 3 parameters but currently passing only 2 parameter ?

Comment: do like     `TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(Search.this, todoCursor,0);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its from an example okay I didnt notice that ill fixt it

Comment: @Moudiz: In example which you are following, author forget to create a `constructor` in `TodoCursorAdapter` class which takes two parameters but creating object of `TodoCursorAdapter` class using constructor with two params. and constructor which takes two parameter is deprecated now as see here [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in `TodoCursorAdapter` class constructor which is taking 3 parameters but currently passing only 2 parameter:

```
TodoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new TodoCursorAdapter(Search.this, todoCursor,0);
```

Last parameter value either `0` or `1`(true/false)